# Debug release apk using chrome dev tools

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools

My app connects to the internet in development, however, the apk uploaded to the play store does not pull down data from the api.

How can I debug the release apk using chrome dev tools?

I have the following permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If debug the API response, you do it by setting up the proxy, for that you can use the `Charles proxy` .
guide https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/